# Popping consecutive view controllers and returning to main view controller (using navigation controller)

Tags: swift3, uikit

I'm following the Firebase-Chat-Messenger example in the "let's build that app" Youtube videos, and it works fine. 
However, I'm testing integration inside a test application :

My test app has a menu with buttons and one of them is for the chat, which takes us to a similar interface (login menu and so on, anything beyond it is similar to the example in the tutorial. But you don't need to check it to answer my question).

Main menu button => Login/Register interface => Chat interface

I can't find a way to dismiss the chat interface to return to the main menu of the app, dismiss always returns to the  login/register interface and sometimes causes errors. Could you suggest a good solution to use for this?

tl;dr : How to dismiss two or more views and return to main view (main menu) of app?

P.S : I'm new to Swift and still struggling with some basic elements, Sorry if the question seems too simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `popToRootViewController(animated:)` to pop to the root view controller, or `popToViewController(_:animated:)` and provide the spicific controller you'd like to pop to.

Comment: how to declare it exactly? i tried self.popToRootViewController(animated:) in the button click action, and it didn't show (autocomplete code) and it doesn't recognise it. Again I apologize as I'm a beginner.

Comment: Then take some courses. It's a method of the navigation controller, so `self.navigationController.popTo...`.